# How to create a make http request on initialization flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to load data from a `Future` on page initialization, I tried updating the state which was initially set to an empty array but I think I am probably doing it wrong.

My flutter knowledge is very limited so Could someone kindly help with what I am doing wrong.

this is where the http request is being made

```
class TransactionService {
  static const API = 'http://localhost:5000';

  static Future<List<MoneyTransactionModel>> getMoneyTransactions() async {
    final response = await http.get(API + '/api/auth/transactions');
    // if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    //   final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    //   print(jsonData);
      return [
        new MoneyTransactionModel(
            id: "1",
            productId: "lime",
            entryType: "sold",
            quantity: "60kg",
            unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
            paidBy: "mtn",
            createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
        new MoneyTransactionModel(
            id: "2",
            productId: "Travetine",
            entryType: "sold",
            quantity: "60kg",
            unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
            paidBy: "mtn",
            createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
        new MoneyTransactionModel(
            id: "3",
            productId: "Travetine",
            entryType: "sold",
            quantity: "60kg",
            unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
            paidBy: "mtn",
            createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
        new MoneyTransactionModel(
            id: "4",
            productId: "lime",
            entryType: "sold",
            quantity: "60kg",
            unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
            paidBy: "mtn",
            createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
      ];
    // } else {
    //   throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    // }
    // return APIResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }

  
}
```

this is where I tried to get and use the data from that request

```
class TransactionTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TransactionTableState();
  }
}

class _TransactionTableState extends State {
  // TransactionService get service => GetIt.I<TransactionService>();
  List<MoneyTransactionModel> transactions = [];

  // _TransactionTableState() {
  //   // print(service.getMoneyTransactions());
  //   TransactionService
  //       .getMoneyTransactions()
  //       .then((List<MoneyTransactionModel> val) => setState(() {
  //             transactions = val;
  //           }));
  //   print(transactions);
  // }

  @override
  void initState() {
    TransactionService.getMoneyTransactions()
        .then((List<MoneyTransactionModel> val) => setState(() {
              transactions = val;
            }));
    // transactions = TransactionService.getMoneyTransactions();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(transactions);
    return Expansionpanel(transactions: transactions);
  }
}
```

the commented part should provide an idea on what I have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the trouble is coming from this line:

```
final response = await http.get(API + '/api/auth/transactions');
```

Maybe there is an error in the url?

If you swap that line out for a dummy future:

```
final response = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
```

Everything else works. Here's the code I tested:

```
class TransactionService {
  static const API = 'http://localhost:5000';

  static Future<List<MoneyTransactionModel>> getMoneyTransactions() async {
    final response = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      return [
        new MoneyTransactionModel(
            id: "1",
            productId: "lime",
            entryType: "sold",
            quantity: "60kg",
            unitPrice: "240rwf/kg",
            paidBy: "mtn",
            createdAt: "2020-04-20T00:15:08.932Z"),
      ];
  }
}

class MoneyTransactionModel{
  final id;
  final productId;
  final entryType;
  final quantity;
  final unitPrice;
  final paidBy;
  final createdAt;

  MoneyTransactionModel({this.id, this.productId, this.entryType, this.quantity, this.unitPrice, this.paidBy, this.createdAt});
}

class TransactionTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TransactionTableState();
  }
}

class _TransactionTableState extends State {
  List<MoneyTransactionModel> transactions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    TransactionService.getMoneyTransactions()
        .then((List<MoneyTransactionModel> val) => setState(() {
              transactions = val;
            }));
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('transactions: $transactions');
    return Container();
  }
}
```